# Postgres returns [null] instead of [] for array_agg of join table

Tags: postgresql, left-join, database-normalization

I'm selecting some objects and their tags in Postgres. The schema is fairly simple, three tables:

**objects** `id`

**taggings** `id | object_id | tag_id`

**tags** `id | tag`

I'm joining the tables like this, using `array_agg` to aggregate the tags into one field:

```
SELECT objects.*,
    array_agg(tags.tag) AS tags,
FROM objects
LEFT JOIN taggings ON objects.id = taggings.object_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
```

However, if the object has no tags, Postgres returns this:

```
[ null ]
```

instead of an an empty array. **How can I return an empty array when there are no tags?** I have double checked that I don't have a null tag being returned.

The [aggregate docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) say "The coalesce function can be used to substitute zero or an empty array for null when necessary". I tried `COALESCE(ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag)) as tags` but it still returns an array with null. I have tried making the second parameter numerous things (such as `COALESCE(ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag), ARRAY())`, but they all result in syntax errors.

Comment: IMHO aggregation should return empty array, not sure why they decided to return `null`. There may be a reason, but something returning an array should not return `null`.

Comment: Whoever came up with this is insane, empty array is clearly the identity element of `array_agg` just like the 0 is identity element of `count`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Since 9.4 one can restrict an aggregate function call to proceed only rows that match a certain criterion: `array_agg(tags.tag) filter (where tags.tag is not null)`

Comment: If all `tags.tag` are null, this returns `null`, not an empty array. Is there a way to return an empty array by default?

Comment: `coalesce(array_agg(tags.tag) filter (where tags.tag is not null), '{}')`

Comment: From @AlexeyBashtanov's comment, if you want to fall back to an empty array instead of an empty object, just switch `'{}'` to `'[]'`.

Comment: @bsplosion Postgres array literals are `'{}'`

Comment: @xlm that's odd - it doesn't work that way for me on Postgres 14 (it returns an object literal with `'{}'`).

Comment: @bsplosion maybe you have an extension installed. From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT): _To write an array value as a literal constant, enclose the element values within curly braces and separate them by commas_

Answer (score 91):

Another option might be `array_remove(..., NULL)` ([introduced in 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html)) if `tags.tag` is `NOT NULL` (otherwise you might want to keep `NULL` values in the array, but in that case, you can't distinguish between a single existing `NULL` tag and a `NULL` tag due to the `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT objects.*,
     array_remove(array_agg(tags.tag), NULL) AS tags,
FROM objects
LEFT JOIN taggings ON objects.id = taggings.object_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
```

If no tags are found, an empty array is returned.

Comment: I chose this answer, perhaps unfairly to the others, because it involves much less query modification, and I don't care about the null tag case here.

Comment: This is the answer I used too, but for those wishing to learn more about the 'why', see Patrick's answer below along with the aggregate function documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Any way to use this with jsob_agg?

Comment: Since `NULL` tags are very likely to be invalid, I also think that this is a fine answer.

Answer (score 23):

The docs say that when you are aggregating zero rows, then you get a null value, and the note about using `COALESCE` is addressing this specific case.

This does not apply to your query, because of the way a `LEFT JOIN` behaves - when it finds *zero* matching rows, it returns *one* row, filled with nulls (and the aggregate of one null row is an array with one null element).

You might be tempted to blindly replace `[NULL]` with `[]` in the output, but then you lose the ability to distiguish between **objects with no tags** and **tagged objects where `tags.tag` is null**. Your application logic and/or integrity constraints may not allow this second case, but that's all the more reason not to suppress a null tag if it does manage to sneak in.

You can identify an object with no tags (or in general, tell when a `LEFT JOIN` found no matches) by checking whether the field on the other side of the join condition is null. So in your case, just replace

```
array_agg(tags.tag)
```

with

```
CASE
  WHEN taggings.object_id IS NULL
  THEN ARRAY[]::text[]
  ELSE array_agg(tags.tag)
END
```

Comment: I think this is a better explanation and answer, except I note that it requires `taggings.object_id` to be added to a `GROUP BY` clause in order to avoid syntax error `ERROR:  42803: column "taggings.object_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` -- does adding this clause alter the final results at all?

Comment: @user9645: Assuming that the original query had a `GROUP BY objects.id` (which is needed to avoid this same error), changing it to `GROUP BY objects.id, taggings.object_id` won't affect the grouping (the `JOIN` condition ensures that a given `objects.id` value can never be associated with multiple distinct `taggings.object_id` values).

Comment: Nick - Thanks I thought so but was not positive.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says that an array containing `NULL` is returned. If you want to convert that to an empty array, then you need to do some minor magic:

```
SELECT objects.id,
    CASE WHEN length((array_agg(tags.tag))[1]) > 0
    THEN array_agg(tags.tag) 
    ELSE ARRAY[]::text[] END AS tags
FROM objects
LEFT JOIN taggings ON objects.id = taggings.object_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
GROUP BY 1;
```

This assumes that the tags are of `text` type (or any of its variants); modify the cast as required.

The trick here is that the first (and only) element in a `[NULL]` array has a length of 0, so if any data is returned from `tags` you return the aggregate, otherwise construct an empty array of the right type.

Incidentally, the statement in the documentation about using `coalesce()` is a bit crummy: what is meant is that if you do not want `NULL` as a result, you can use `coalesce()` to turn that into a `0` or some other output of your choosing. But you need to apply that to the *array elements* instead of the array, which, in your case, would not provide a solution.

Comment: Yep, you actually want the reverse of `coalesce`, `nullif`, if the question really is as it appears.

Comment: `length(NULL)` is `NULL`, not `0`. `length(NULL) > 0` is also `NULL`, which happens to fall through to the `ELSE` case. But so does `length('') > 0`, and I don't think this is the desired behaviour.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html  It's kind of buried in the documentation but the relevant text is "It should be noted that except for count, these functions return a null value when no rows are selected. In particular, sum of no rows returns null, not zero as one might expect, and array_agg returns null rather than an empty array when there are no input rows."

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(array_agg(tags.tag), '{NULL}'), '{}') AS tags,
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this answer is a little late, but I wanted to share with you that another querying strategy is possible as well: performing the aggregation in a a separate (common) table expression.

```
WITH cte_tags AS (
  SELECT
    taggings.object_id,
    array_agg(tags.tag) AS tags
  FROM
    taggings
    INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
  GROUP BY
    taggings.object_id
)
SELECT
  objects.*,
  cte_tags.tags
FROM
  objects
  LEFT JOIN cte_tags ON cte_tags.object_id = objects.id
```

Instead of an array with a single element of NULL, you will now get NULL instead of an array.

If you really want an empty array instead of NULL in your results, you can use the `COALESCE` function...:

```
WITH cte_tags AS (
  SELECT
    taggings.object_id,
    array_agg(tags.tag) AS tags
  FROM
    taggings
    INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
  GROUP BY
    taggings.object_id
)
SELECT
  objects.*,
  COALESCE(cte_tags.tags, '{}') AS tags
FROM
  objects
  LEFT JOIN cte_tags ON cte_tags.object_id = objects.id
```

...or use array-to-array concatenation:

```
WITH cte_tags AS (
  SELECT
    taggings.object_id,
    array_agg(tags.tag) AS tags
  FROM
    taggings
    INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
  GROUP BY
    taggings.object_id
)
SELECT
  objects.*,
  cte_tags.tags || '{}' AS tags
FROM
  objects
  LEFT JOIN cte_tags ON cte_tags.object_id = objects.id
```

Answer (score -2):

I replaced

```
array_to_json(array_agg(col_name))
```

with

```
array_to_json(coalesce(array_agg(col_name), ARRAY[]::record[]))
```

so that instead of returning a null JSON value I got an empty JSON array