# Properly dealing with hierarchies in Rust & SQLx

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I am working on a REST API written in Rust using actix-web, SQLx and PostgreSQL for storage.
Let's suppose this is my schema (expressed as Rust structs):

```rust
struct User {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub email: String
    // And so on...
}

struct Customer {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub user_id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    // And so on...
}
```

My current goal is to implement an endpoint, that returns all users with their customers nested. I.e. like this:

```json
// GET /users
// Response from endpoint
[{
  "id": "uuid-1",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "customers": [{
    "id": "uuid-customer-1",
    "name": "Customer 1"
  }, {
    "id": "uuid-customer-2",
    "name": "Customer 2"
  }]
}]
```

The payload above could be expressed using the following structs:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct CustomerData {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct UserData {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub email: String,
    pub customers: Vec<CustomerData>
}
```

Using SQLx macro `query_as!` I came up with following solution attempt:

```rust
let result = sqlx::query_as!(
    UserData,
    r#"
    SELECT U.id, U.email, array_agg((C.id, C.name)) as "customers" FROM users U 
    INNER JOIN customers C ON user_id = U.id
    GROUP BY U.id
    "#
)
    .fetch_all(pool.as_ref())
    .await?;
```

This, however fails, because the result returned by `array_agg` is of type `RECORD[]`, which SQLx apparently does not yet support.

This issue got me wondering:

- Is there a way to get SQLx to properly map the result of `array_agg` to `customers`?
- Given, that my actual schema has at least few more levels in the hierarchy, is this even the right way to go? Would it be "better" to split it in several queries and piecewise construct the response?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation I did indeed. I've posted an answer to my own question. If there is anything, that I can clarify, please let me know and I'll take care of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explanation ahead; TL;DR at the bottom.

After more digging, I found a solution, that is actually quite obvious once you get used to SQLx and Rust.

So, the issue is, that SQLx considers the return value of `ARRAY_AGG()` to be of type `RECORD[]`. Luckily, SQLX allows us to tell which type we expect by type casting in their DSL.

So, to solve the issue, we first need to cast our `RECORD[]` to `Vec<CustomerData>` in the query, which can be done like this:

```rust
    SELECT 
        id, 
        email, 
        ARRAY_AGG((C.id, C.name)) as "customers: Vec<CustomerData>" 
    FROM users 
    JOIN customers C ON user_id = U.id
    GROUP BY id, email
```

Additionally, we need to implement the Trait `sqlx::Type` for `CustomerData`.
Luckily there's a macro for that:

```rust
#[derive(sqlx::Type, Serialize)]
struct CustomerData {
    // ...
}
```

Last but not least, there is a final issue to resolve: `ARRAY_AGG` either returns `NULL` or an array. This can be solved in three ways:

- Nullable types are treated as `Option<T>` by SQLx. So the field `customers` should be of type `Option<Vec<CustomerData>>` in the Struct.
- Tell SQLx to not worry, be happy and assert, that the value is not null, by using an exclamation mark in the query cast. I.e. like this: `... as "customers!: Vec<CustomerData>`
- Use SQL to return an empty array (other solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108946/postgres-returns-null-instead-of-for-array-agg-of-join-table)), when `ARRAY_AGG` returns NULL:

```sql
    SELECT 
        id, 
        email, 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(ARRAY_AGG((C.id, C.name)), '{NULL}'), '{}') as "customers: Vec<CustomerData>" 
    FROM users 
    JOIN customers C ON user_id = U.id
    GROUP BY id, email
```

---

This solution works, if hierarchies depth is no more than 1. You'll hit a wall due to a bug in the SQLx' type resolver, if you nest deeper. The Issue regarding this can be found [here](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/1672#issuecomment-1358703261).

---

TL;DR:

- Derive `sqlx::Type` on the nested type.
- Cast the query result using SQLx' DSL using the following **"as"** part

```sql
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(JOINED.id) as "field_name!: Vec<AggregateType>"
FROM ...
```

EDIT: To my dismay, custom enums additionally count as a level in the hierachy. Thus, if your nested type has an enum, this is not supported. Even for the current version 0.7.1.

Comment: this does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to parse array of strings to a struct attribute. What worked is:

1. Creating a struct like this, using derive `sqlx::FromRow` and `sqlx::types::Json` for an attribute type:

```
#[derive(sqlx::FromRow)]
struct RegionsTopRow {
    region: String,
    top_gifts: sqlx::types::Json<Vec<String>>,
}
```

// It's better to use the full path `sqlx::types::Json` as there are many different Json types

2. Using `json_agg()` in PostgreSQL

```
sql = r#"
    SELECT r.name as region, json_agg(gift_name) as top_gifts
    FROM grouped_orders go
    LEFT JOIN regions r ON r.id = go.region_id
    GROUP BY r.name;"
#;
```

3. Using the struct (like `RegionsTopRow` in the example above) in an sqlx query:

```
let r = sqlx::query_as::<_, RegionsTopRow>(sql)
   .fetch_all(&state.pool)
   .await
```