# Sqlx: Convert / Retrieve Postgresql column of type RECORD[] into a struct field of type Vec<_>

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I have the following two structs:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Login {
    email: String,
    oidc_id: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Account {
    id: Uuid,
    created: NaiveDateTime,
    private_key: String,
    public_key: String,
    logins: Vec<Login>
}
```

I want to use them to read data from Postgres via [Sqlx](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/index.html) like this:

```
let result = sqlx::query_as!(
    Account,
    "select *, ARRAY(
        select ROW(email, oidc_id)
            from logins where logins.account_id = accounts.id
        ) as logins from accounts"
).fetch_all(pool).await?;
```

Is it possible to get this working without creating a custom record type in Postgres? I tried to implement `FromRow` but Sqlx still complained about the unsupported type `RECORD[]`. I also tried to derive [sqlx::Type](https://docs.rs/sqlx-postgres/0.7.1/sqlx_postgres/types/index.html#composite-types) but without success.

Retrieving data like this would be very convenient, but not if I would have to declare a custom record type for each possible query.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257309/properly-dealing-with-hierarchies-in-rust-sqlx/76476596#76476596)).

Also, I am not sure whether I understand the goal of your query. So, for my example, let's assume you just want to retrieve all accounts with their logins:

```rs
let accounts = sqlx::query_as!(
    Account,
    r#"
    SELECT
        A.id,
        A.created,
        A.private_key,
        A.public_key,
        array_agg((L.email, L.oidc_id)) as "logins!: Vec<Login>"
    FROM accounts A
    JOIN logins L ON A.account_id = L.account_id
    "#
)
.fetch_all(pool)
.await?;
```

However, for this to work, you need to `#[derive(sqlx::Type)]` your nested type.

---

This works because the `as "logins!: Vec<Login>` provides additional type informations to SQLx. Bear in mind, that due to limitations, you can only nest your date by one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct RawAccount {
    id: Uuid,
    created: NaiveDateTime,
    private_key: String,
    public_key: String,
}

let raw_accounts: Vec<RawAccount> = sqlx::query_as!(
    RawAccount,
    "SELECT id, created, private_key, public_key FROM accounts"
)
.fetch_all(pool)
.await?;

let mut accounts: Vec<Account> = Vec::new();

for raw_account in raw_accounts {
    let logins: Vec<Login> = sqlx::query_as!(
        Login,
        "SELECT email, oidc_id FROM logins WHERE account_id = $1",
        raw_account.id
    )
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await?;

    let account = Account {
        id: raw_account.id,
        created: raw_account.created,
        private_key: raw_account.private_key,
        public_key: raw_account.public_key,
        logins,
    };

    accounts.push(account);
}
```

Comment: That creates A LOT of additional queries to the database, if the result set gets bigger. You should never do this in real world code working with real world data. If you have to resort to such a solution, you should at least use an IN statement and request multiple logins rows at once.

Answer (score -3):

From my experience with sqlx I can say that 99% of issues can be solved by type casts, [including this one](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/349#issuecomment-636285752). From the postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS):

> By default, the value created by a `ROW` expression is of an *anonymous record type*. If necessary, it can be cast to a named composite type — either the row type of a table, or a *composite type* created with `CREATE TYPE AS`. An explicit cast might be needed to avoid ambiguity.
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TYPE myrowtype AS (f1 int, f2 text, f3 numeric);
>
> SELECT CAST(ROW(11, 'this is a test', 2.5) AS myrowtype);
> ```

Giving it a name allows sqlx to match the type on the rust side, so that may work. The other way around is a conversion to a table type, syntax: `ROW(...)::table`:

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT ROW(email, oidc_id)::logins
      FROM logins
      WHERE logins.account_id = accounts.id
  ) AS logins
FROM accounts;
```

Comment: OP said: `Is it possible to get this working without creating a custom record type in Postgres?` Why would you provide this answer?

Comment: Apparently, cause SQLx doesn't receive enough information from Postgres and there is [no way](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/349#issuecomment-636415989) to do it.

Comment: You should not provide an answer that does not answer what OP is asking.

Comment: Achim is looking for an answer from a reputable source, I provided the link. If you can't improve the answer, please, don't tell me what to do, it's rude.

Comment: You did not provide an answer though. Op said `but not if I would have to declare a custom record type for each possible query.` and you went on to provide an answer where Op would have to do that every time. Also, OP saw your answer and still requested another answer. Sorry that calling out a non-answer is rude.